# hypothesis testing two samples

Tags: statistics

I have two samples with different amount of element and I wonder how to do t.test in R to see if it is the same distribution between them. My teacher had on example but there the samples had the same amount of element and he took sample1 - sample2 and then check for mu=0.

How do I do it with two different lengths of the samples?

Answer (score 0):

If sample sizes differ, it doesn't make a difference in the R code. R counts the number of elements in each of the two data vectors and uses those for $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Here is an
example in which I have generated two vectors of different lengths from different normal distributions. The means are different, so we expect a small P-value. I'm doing a 2-sided test.

By default R does a Welch (separate variances) test. If this were a pooled two-sample t test we would have df = 10 + 12 - 2 = 20. The output from the test below has a smaller df. If you used parameter 'var.eq=T', you would get a pooled test with df=20.

**It is a quirk of R that the sample sizes are not given in the output. this may be the source of your confusion.** But you could get them in the case below with 'length(x1)' and 'length(x2)' (not shown below).

If you use the seed shown, you will get the same fake data I did. If you change (or omit) the 'set.seed' statement, you will get different data and somewhat different test results.

`> set.seed(1234)
> x1 = rnorm(15, 100, 10);  x2 = rnorm(10, 115, 12)
> t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2 
t = -3.9081, df = 15.868, p-value = 0.001270
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -26.52207  -7.85962 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 96.62703 113.81788`